# In Oracle Apex how to you set pagination for a report based on a column value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have this table with a column of type Date called "Creation_Date" that contains the creation date for each row:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| TaskName     | Validated_By | Creation_Date |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| Task A       | Jim          | 12/1/2022     |
| Task B       | John         | 12/1/2022     |
| Task C       | Jill         | 12/1/2022     |
| Task D       | John         | 11/30/2022    |
| Task E       | John         | 11/30/2022    |
| Task F       | Bill         | 11/30/2022    |
| Task G       | Goerge       | 11/29/2022    |
| Task H       | George       | 11/29/2022    |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want a classic report for this table in Oracle Apex to appear to the user like this:

```
12/1/2022 >
+--------------+--------------+
| TaskName     | Validated_By |
+--------------+--------------+
| Task A       | Jim          |
| Task B       | John         |
| Task C       | Jill         |
+--------------+--------------+
```

And when they click on the arrow next to the date the rows for the previous day show up:

```
< 11/30/2022 >
+--------------+--------------+
| TaskName     | Validated_By |
+--------------+--------------+
| Task D       | John         |
| Task E       | John         |
| Task F       | Bill         |
+--------------+--------------+
```

And when they press again, the rows for the day before that show up, etc:

```
< 11/29/2022 >
+--------------+--------------+
| TaskName     | Validated_By |
+--------------+--------------+
| Task G       | Goerge       |
| Task H       | George       |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Is there a built-in way in Oracle Apex to do this for a Classic Report (or for an Interactive Report, doesn't matter) ?

Comment: nothing built in, but there's probably a few options to help you get there. Faceted search may give you something in the desired ballpark https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/apex-192-faceted-search

Comment: @Scott so for the facet, what would be its "Type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Scott statet, nothing built in but this shouldn't be that hard to code (for classic report/interactive report). Make sure you have an item `P1_DATE` that holds the date for which the rows are shown.

```
--- create test data
CREATE TABLE test_data (task, name, dt) AS 
(

SELECT 'Task A','Jim',    TO_DATE('12/1/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'Task B','John',   TO_DATE('12/1/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'Task C','Jill',   TO_DATE('12/1/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL     
SELECT 'Task D','John',   TO_DATE('11/30/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Task E','John',   TO_DATE('11/30/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Task F','Bill',   TO_DATE('11/30/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Task G','Goerge', TO_DATE('11/29/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 'Task H','George', TO_DATE('11/29/2022','MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL 
);
```

###### Report

Report source would be:

```
SELECT task, name, dt FROM test_data WHERE dt = TO_DATE(:P1_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

###### Previous button configuration:

- Page Item `P1_DATE_PREV`.
- Source:

```
SELECT MAX(dt) FROM  test_data WHERE dt < TO_DATE(:P1_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

- To hide button if there is no previous date: Add Server side condition of "rows returned"

```
SELECT 1 FROM  test_data WHERE dt < TO_DATE(:P1_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

- The "previous" button would redirect to Page 1 and set `P1_PAGE` to `P1_PAGE_PREV`

###### Next button configuration:

- Page Item `P1_DATE_NEXT`.
- Source:

```
SELECT MIN(dt) FROM  test_data WHERE dt > TO_DATE(:P1_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

- To hide button if there is no next date: Add Server side condition of "rows returned"

```
SELECT 1 FROM  test_data WHERE dt > TO_DATE(:P1_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

- The "next" button would redirect to Page 1 and set `P1_PAGE` to `P1_PAGE_NEXT`

Comment: I have a related question, if the report and the Next and Previous buttons are all in the same region, will refreshing only this region lead to the Server-Side conditions of the buttons being checked again? Cause I tried it and the server-side conditions seem to be ignored.

Comment: Server-side conditions are only evaluated at page rendering time, so what you are seeing is expected behaviour. My solution above is written under the assumption that full page is refreshed and redirects are used. If you want to refresh region only that will not work. I believe the button target will not change on button refresh.
For a partial page refresh solution you need to use dynamic actions to manage the state of the page items and the button actions/button visibility. It's a bit more work